# Ubuntu Server(on Raspberry pi 3B) Unable to open DISPLAY with JavaFX program

Tags: java, javafx, ubuntu-server

I made a Javafx program which reads a .json file and builds it into a line chart png file. It works perfectly on my Windows PC but I cant make it run on my Rapberry pi 3B with ubuntu server Installed.

My program: https://github.com/MHeiIT/JsonToGraphPNG

The Error message I get:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH -jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JsonToGraphPNG/target/JsonToGraphPNG-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /var/lib/jenkins/mika/userdata.json /var/lib/jenkins/mika/chart.png
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$6(GtkApplication.java:173)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:171)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:258)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more
```

If you need further information to help me than write a comment.

Thx for every help

Answer (score 1):

Check this forum https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=67781
it might help